# Append a multidimensional array to the bottom of a different multidimensional array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, append

I have two arrays with n dimensions arr1 and arr2.  I want to add arr2 to the bottom of arr1

i.e. I want to append arr2 to arr1 as rows, not columns.

I use this for one-dimensional arrays to add arr2 to arr1 as columns, but I can not get how to alter it so as to add rows instead of columns

So if

```
arr1 =  [[Id, From, To], [1.0, AA1, BB1], [2.0, AA2, BB2], [3.0, AA3, BB3]]

arr2 = [[Id, From, To], [4.0, AA4, BB4], [5.0, AA5, BB5], [6.0, AA6, BB6]]

result =  [[Id, From, To], [1.0, AA1, BB1], [2.0, AA2, BB2], [3.0, AA3, BB3], [4.0, AA4, BB4], [5.0, AA5, BB5], [6.0, AA6, BB6]]
```

Thanks

```
function conatArr(arr1, arr2) {

 var result = arr1.map(function(row, i){
 return row.concat(arr2[i]);
})
return result
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a simple example of the two arrays and the resulting array?

Comment: Reverse parameters `(arr2, arr1)`

Comment: I forgot the example data, sorry about that

Comment: I tried reversing the parameters and it did not work, or I did it incorrectly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use [`...spread syntax`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to merge two arrays

```js
let arr1 =  [['Id', 'From', 'To'], [1.0, 'AA1', 'BB1'], [2.0, 'AA2', 'BB2'], [3.0, 'AA3', 'BB3']]

let arr2 = [['Id', 'From', 'To'], [4.0, 'AA4', 'BB4'], [5.0, 'AA5', 'BB5'], [6.0, 'AA6', 'BB6']]

let final = [...arr1, ...arr2.slice(1)]

console.log(final)
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply [push](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp) into result

```js
arr1 =  [["Id", "From", "To"], [1.0, "AA1", "BB1"], [2.0, "AA2", "BB2"], [3.0, "AA3", "BB3"]]

arr2 = [["Id", "From", "To"], [4.0, "AA4", "BB4"], [5.0, "AA5", "BB5"], [6.0, "AA6", "BB6"]]

var result = [];

result.push(arr1[0]);

for (i = 1; i < arr1.length; i++)
{
  result.push(arr1[i]);
  result.push(arr2[i]);  
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I tried to figure out a solution like this and failed, thanks for showing me how to do this

Answer (score 1):

Try this, not very clever but it works on your example data

```
function combineArrays(shtName, arr1,arr2) {
 var sht = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(shtName);
 var result =[];

for (i=0;i< arr1.length + arr2.length;i++) {
  if(i < arr1.length) {result[i]=arr1[i]}
  else{result[i] = arr2[i-arr1.length]}
}
```

Here is the better way:

```
function conatArrAsRows(shtName, arr1, arr2, postback) {
var sht = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(shtName);

var result = arr1.concat(arr2);

if(postback == true) {sht.getRange(1,1,result.length,result[0].length).setValues(result)};
return result
}
```